# Linking issue in a makefile

Tags: makefile, bison, build-dependencies

I am writing a compiler using Bison and Flex and have been working until recently with a `make all` target (I know its not that good of an idea). I am now remaking my directory structure and remaking the makefile properly. Currently I have:

/Compiler

--- /src

---------- c_parser.y

---------- c_lexer.l

---------- AST.cpp

---------- AST.h

---------- Context.cpp

---------- Context.h

--- /bin

I want to obtain `bin/c_codegen` which depends on AST, Context and the outputs of bison and flex (`c_parser.tab.c c_parser.tab.h c_lexer.yy.c`). However c_lexer.yy.c also depends on `c_parser.tab.h` which is created in the `src/` directory. This is throwing errors of undeclared functions (which are declared in c_parser.tab.h), in the rule:

```
bin/lex.yy.o: src/lex.yy.c src/c_parser.tab.h
    g++ -std=c++11 -w -I ./src -c -o bin/lex.yy.o src/lex.yy.c
```

Error:

```
src/lex.yy.c: In function 'void yy_init_buffer(YY_BUFFER_STATE, FILE*)':
src/lex.yy.c:1690:59: error: 'fileno' was not declared in this scope
         b->yy_is_interactive = file ? (isatty( fileno(file) ) > 0) : 0;
```

I believe this has to do with searching for the header files and therefore tried using the `-I` flag but it did not work. The full make file is:

```
bin/c_codegen: bin/lex.yy.o bin/c_parser.tab.o bin/AST.o bin/context.o
    g++ -std=c++11 -w -I ./src -o bin/c_codegen bin/lex.yy.o bin/c_parser.tab.o bin/AST.o bin/context.o

bin/lex.yy.o: src/lex.yy.c src/c_parser.tab.h
    g++ -std=c++11 -w -I ./src -c -o bin/lex.yy.o src/lex.yy.c 

bin/c_parser.tab.o: src/c_parser.tab.c src/c_parser.tab.h
    g++ -std=c++11 -w -c -o bin/c_parser.tab.o src/c_parser.tab.c 

bin/AST.o: src/AST.cpp src/AST.h
    g++ -std=c++11 -w -c -o bin/AST.o src/AST.cpp

bin/context.o: src/context.cpp src/context.h
    g++ -std=c++11 -w -c -o bin/context.o src/context.cpp

src/c_parser.tab.c src/c_parser.tab.h: src/c_parser.y
    win_bison -d -o src/c_parser.tab.c -v src/c_parser.y

src/lex.yy.c: src/c_parser.tab.h
    flex  -o src/lex.yy.c src/c_lexer.l 

all: 
    flex  -o src/lex.yy.c src/c_lexer.l 
    win_bison -d -o src/c_parser.tab.c -v src/c_parser.y --warnings=none 
    g++ -std=c++11 -w -o bin/c_codegen src/lex.yy.c src/c_parser.tab.c src/AST.cpp src/context.cpp

clean:
    rm -f src/lex.yy.c src/c_parser.tab.h src/c_parser.tab.c bin/*.o bin/c_codegen tmp_*.txt
```

Comment: did you include stdio.h in your lex code?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem for those interested:

Turns out that I hadn't noticed that at the same time I made the new makefile I had also introduced new rules in my lexer that use `strdup`. I had tried this changes in a linux computer. Then now working in my own computer with minGW it was failing due to the known problem of minGW with string conversion problems, and not with the makefile.